# Are all the division rings simple?

Tags: ring-theory

I have just read two facts related to simple rings.

(1) A commutative ring $R$ with identity is simple if and only if $R$ is a field.

(2) Let $R$ be a ring with identity.Then each ideal of the ring $M_{n} (R)$ of all $n \times n$ matrices over $R$ is of the form $M_{n} (T)$, where $T$ is some ideal of $R$.

As a corollary of (2) it can be easily proved that if $R$ is field then $M_{n} (R)$ becomes simple.Which shows that if a ring $R$ with identity is simple then $R$ may not be a division ring.

Now my question is :

Are all the division rings simple? What are the examples of simple and non-simple division rings?Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you know the result that if an ideal $I$ contains $1_R$, then $I=R$? What does that tell you about non-zero ideals of a division ring?

Comment: Oh...Sorry @Jyrki Lahtonen every non zero ideal of division ring contains some non zero elements which are units and hence the ideal contains identity of the division ring and cosequently it becomes the whole division ring.So a division ring has no non trivial ideal and therefore every division ring is simple like every field.Here commutativity doesn't matter.Isn't it?

Comment: Correct. Well done!

Comment: Thanks @Jyrki Lahtonen for your hint.I should have thought about it a bit more before asking this silly one.